# Fast computation of node distances to set of nodes

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

For each node (pink nodes) in an undirected/unweighted graph, I want to compute the closest distance to a given set of connected nodes (red nodes). It is essential that the computation is fast, also on large graphs (~4000 nodes) and for a large set of connected nodes. See the illustration below. What is the best algorithm/graph library for me to do this?

[image]

I tried to do something like that with [NetworkX](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) - [shortest_path_length](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length.html#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path_length) already, but it is too slow. Especially for a large set of connected red nodes.

```py
import networkx as nx

all_distances = []
for node in red_nodes:
    distances = nx.shortest_path_length(graph, source=node) # compute distances to all nodes in the graph from the source node
    all_distances.append(distances)
shortest_distances = filter_for_shortest_distance(all_distances)
```

Here is an example on how to access a graph that I am working with. The red nodes could be any subset of connected nodes in the graph.

```py
# Import navis
import navis

# Load one of the example neurons
sk = navis.example_neurons(n=1, kind='skeleton')

# Inspect the neuron graph
graph = sk.get_graph_nx()
```

Comment: Is the graph always a tree (as in the drawing)? If not, is there any other structure in it (modular?). What is the ratio of red/pink nodes? This question would benefit from example data, ideally more than one network.

Comment: The graph is most likely always a tree. The red/pink ratio varies, but on average the graph contains 1/4 red nodes 3/4 pink nodes. I added an example of how to access a graph that I am working with.

Comment: So this is a dendritic tree? Then you can immediately simplify the problem by cutting the tree above the red node closest to the soma into a pure pink subtree and a mixed subtree. All pink nodes in the pure pink subtree will have the red node at the cut point as their closest red.

Comment: Out of interest (fellow neuroscientist): what is red, what is pink?

Comment: Also, it bears mentioning for other users that `TreeNeurons` in `navis` are __directed__, unweighted networks.

Comment: For the mixed tree, starting from each pink node, I would recursively call `nx.predecessors`,  until I hit a red node (which is guaranteed as a red node is the root of the mixed tree).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dijkstra's algorithm with multiple start points:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import typing

Node = int

def get_distances(graph: nx.Graph, red_nodes: typing.Set[Node]) -> typing.Dict[Node, int]:
    node_to_distance = {}
    node_to_neighbours = graph.adj

    # fill node_to_distance for red nodes and init set of reachable nodes
    reachable = set()
    for node in red_nodes:
        node_to_distance[node] = 0
        for neighbour in node_to_neighbours[node]:
            if neighbour not in red_nodes:
                node_to_distance[neighbour] = 1
                reachable.add(neighbour)

    # for each reachable node add neighbours as reachable nodes with greater distance
    while reachable:
        node = reachable.pop()
        distance = node_to_distance[node]
        for neighbour in node_to_neighbours[node]:
            if distance + 1 < node_to_distance.get(neighbour, len(graph)):
                node_to_distance[neighbour] = distance + 1
                reachable.add(neighbour)

    return node_to_distance

def check():
    g = nx.petersen_graph()
    red_nodes = {1, 2}
    node_to_distance = get_distances(g, red_nodes=red_nodes)
    plt.subplot(121)
    node_colors = ["red" if node in red_nodes else "yellow" for node in g.nodes()]
    nx.draw(g, with_labels=True, node_color=node_colors, labels=node_to_distance)
    plt.show()

check()
```

i've tested it on 40000 nodes graph and it took 42 ms to calc distances with 10000 red nodes